# Zip/Postal Code in Table Rates

Tags: shipping, table-rates, zipcode

Can I use asterisk within the Zip/Postal Code column in the Table Rates in Magento 2?

For example, if I wanted to include every BT & IV postcode would the CSV file pick up:

BT*
IV*

[image]

Please see image for reference.

Or, do I have to add in each BT & IV postcode individually? For example:

BT1 1AA

BT1 1AB

etc

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, the asterisk char `*` works as a wildcard in order to express **all** possible values of the criteria on that specific row and column, but only alone and NOt in combination to other chars.

Comment: Ok, so I will have to write out each Zip/Postal Code individually? Is there any other method of getting around this time consuming task? \

Comment: yes, you have to write each rule for each zip code. i don't think there is a way to go around this. but think of it this way: you write this once and then, whenever something changes, you just use the same file and edit it.

Comment: ok, thank you for your help :)

Comment: you're welcome! i suggest you consider marking the answer solved. cheers!